# Microsoft.Owin upgradation from 4.1.1 to 4.2.2

Tags: .net

I have dot net 4.7.2 framework application. I want to update Microsoft.Owin package from 4.1.1 to 4.2.2. I have changed it through nuget package manager. It is building successfully in local but when I run it it giving me error 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'.

Please let me know what is the exact issue.